# APScheduler duplicating jobs in Flask app hosted on Heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, gunicorn, apscheduler

I have an app structured as below which allows a user to schedule tasks to query FB API each morning, afternoon etc to pull page/post data (3am in this case).

The problem I am experiencing is that the scheduler is executing each job twice which is obviously undesirable. Oddly, the issue doesn’t seem to occur locally, only when in production mode and I am hosting this in Heroku with 1 web dyno and 1 worker dyno, each with only 1 process each. I am therefore leaning towards Heroku being the issue.

I have a page to list the current scheduled jobs and when I inspect it, upon refreshing the page the same job instance will flick between two different values (screenshot below). It is as if there are two BackgroundScheduler's instances running.

[image]

[image]

I suspected this was to do with the BackgroundScheduler being initiated twice (once in flasky.py and again in tasks.py) so I created a temporary solution to stop the double initialising of the BackgroundScheduler and I still experience the same issue and am now stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
-->app
   -->__init__.py
   -->decorators.py
   -->models.py
   -->tasks.py
   -->auth
      -->__init__.py
      -->errors.py
      -->forms.py
      -->views.py
   -->main
      -->__init__.py
      -->errors.py
      -->forms.py
      -->views.py
   -->static
   -->templates
-->migrations
config.py
flasky.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
```

app/flasky.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, session, redirect, url_for, flash
import os
from app import create_app,db
from app.models import User,Role
from datetime import datetime
from flask_migrate import Migrate,upgrade

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
```

app/_ *init* _.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config
from flask_session import Session
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
import rq
from redis import Redis
from flask_login import LoginManager
from worker import conn
import os

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy()
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
migrate = Migrate()
session= Session()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

def create_app(config_name='default'):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app,db)
    session.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    if not scheduler.running:
        scheduler.start()
        jobstore_url = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
        scheduler.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=jobstore_url),'sqlalchemy')

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint

    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint,url_prefix='/auth')

    app.task_queue = rq.Queue('flasky',connection=Redis.from_url(os.environ.get(REDIS_URL)) 

    if app.config['SSL_REDIRECT']:
        from flask_sslify import SSLify
        sslify = SSLify(app)

    return app
```

app/tasks.py

```
from . import create_app,db
from .models import User,Tokens,Files
from .decorators import token_getter
from flask_login import current_user
import requests
import datetime as dt
import urllib
import os

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')

<FUNCTIONS HERE>
```

app/auth/views.py

```
from flask import render_template,url_for,redirect,request,flash,session,current_app,Response
from .. import db,scheduler
from . import auth
from ..models import User,Role,Tokens,Files
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required
from ..decorators import admin_required, token_setter, token_getter,permission_required
import requests
import urllib
from .forms import LoginForm, SubmitConnection, ScheduleJobForm
from app.tasks import refreshed_google_client,test_context
```

app/main/views.py

```
from flask import render_template, session, redirect, url_for, flash,current_app,request
from datetime import datetime
from . import main
from .. import db,scheduler
from ..models import User,Tokens
from .forms import NameForm,AnalyticsForm
from flask_login import login_required,current_user
from ..decorators import admin_required,permission_required
import requests
import rq
from redis import Redis
from app.tasks import refreshed_google_client,load_analytics

@main.route('/ig_sync',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
@permission_required(4)
def ig_sync():
    form = IGAnalyticsForm()
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        from app.tasks import load_ig_sync
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if form.submit_analytics_schedule.data:
                #GET VARIABLES FROM FORM
                scheduler.add_job(func=load_ig_sync,args=[#VARIABLES HERE],trigger='cron',hour=3,id=f'SYNC_IG_{page_name}',jobstore='sqlalchemy')
                return(redirect(url_for('main.job_schedule')))
    return render_template('ig_sync.html',form=form)
```

app/Procfile

```
web: gunicorn flasky:app
worker: rq worker -u $REDIS_URL flasky
```

Comment: Yes, you are definitely creating 2 apps by calling `create_app` in your tasks. Why do you call it there? Do you need something from the app in your tasks? Have you seen [flask-apscheduler](https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler/tree/master/examples), which has an example of how to access the app inside your task. I'm guessing you want your app config for variables etc.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delay in responding. I have been OOO. Yes, i call create_app() in my tasks.py file so that I have access to the app context for my functions.

Comment: Calling it twice is an issue. you should be able to access you app context for the pre-existing app using code from the example I linked.